# How can one function in society (as a householder) without actively arousing (possibly strong) desire, or aversion

Tags: modern-world

If we have no desire or aversion, how can we get up and clean our home, our body, eat more than is needed, or go to work?

If one has indifference towards experiences and/or is equanimous to experiences it would make no difference if ones home or body was dirty. If we were in poverty, or if we had any more food than the immediate needed to subside the pangs of hunger.

It seems to me that these unwholesome mind states are actually needed to function as a person in society (a householder) just to do the above things that one generally needs to do to maintain themselves and a householders life.

Like one needs to have aversion and be disgusted at ones own filth to clean ones home/body or needs to have desire to be clean and to be seen as clean by others (vanity or desire for reputation).

Same with finances, one needs to have desire for material possessions or hopes/desires for a "better" future to actively go out and do more work to earn more wealth than what is actually immediately needed.

Kind of feels like functioning in society itself is the maras trap.

Realistically all one really needs to do to function as a human is ones daily ablutions, have shelter from the elements and enough food to stop the suffering of hunger, which is pretty much what an ordained person does.

Water is needed too of course but except in dire places in the world water is abundant everywhere.

Comment: Understanding desire (tanha) and relinquishing it is a central tenet in the teachings. It is complex and difficult to penetrate even anagamis still have subtle desires. It looks bad but like peeling an onion, remove one layer, it seems to have its uses (as you mentioned). But then peel again, you get another insight and so on. We should not stop investigating too early and proclaim that we have understood the true nature of desire (and aversion). This would be a disservice to ourselves. If tanha is all good, we (likewise the world) should be at peace now. So, there must be something else.

Answer (score 1):

Buddhism refers to two types of desire:

1. Ignorance desire called 'tanha' ('craving').
2. Wise desire called 'Right Intention'.

In Buddhism, we perform our necessary duties guided by wise intention.

Answer (score -1):

Absolutely agreed that desires and aversions are needed for survival in the world. Although indifference and equanimity are different things but we need to differentiate between not having enough to eat and not hungering for a feast.

However, all these desires/aversions/unwholesome states do have their issues. Suppose one day, our neighbour come along and show us the new Lamborghini SUV that they just bought and we go, “Hmmm…”. Then a friend of ours invited us to their house-warming at their big house in an uptown area and we go, “Hmmm…”. Or we go, “What!” when the government announced that they are going to impose or increase the consumption tax next year.

But all these are minor stuff compared to the big ones. Suppose one day, we saw lovey-dovey messages on our partner’s mobile and it’s not from us. Or the boss just called us into his office to hand over a retrenchment letter. Or the doctor informed us on the follow-up that the throat pain we've been suffering for weeks originated from a malignant cancer somewhere else.

Prince Siddhartha was brought up learning the skills to govern a country. One of the things he probably learned is you need to take care of the biggest and most important issues first then the rest will be easy. And the biggest issue he realized is that of **old age, illness and death**. If he could solve this problem then he would have all the time in the world to indulge in almost all of his desires.

If we can solve this same problem and we don’t have money for a new car or a bigger house, we have now to eternity to earn all the money we want. If we can’t find the love of our life, we have all the time to switch partners till we hit the right one. If we don’t like the government of the day, we have all the time to influence and change their policies. But do we?

Our life is like a candle, it burns away until it eventually extinguishes. As a result, we struggle to prioritize the most important things and resources in our limited life. What are our most important goals? How much time should we spend to accumulate the resources to fulfil those goals? And all the while as we are busy working to complete these goals, the clock goes “tick tock, tick tock” and the candle burns lower.